# Why does the button in this greasemonkey script not work on all sites?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

So, I'm writing a script to help keep track of who I've trick or treated on one of my game sites.  I added a button to clear localStorage but the button is unclickable on that site, while it works fine on other sites.

Works [HERE](http://www.aywas.com)

Doesn't work [HERE](http://www.felisfire.com)  On the default dark layout...

Isolated problem script:

```
var box = document.createElement( 'div' );
box.id = 'mySelectBox';
GM_addStyle( 
    ' #mySelectBox {             ' +
    '    background: white;     ' +
    '    border: 2px solid red; ' +
    '    padding: 4px;          ' +
  //'    position: absolute;    ' +
    '    position: fixed;       ' +
    '    top: 8px; left: 8px;   ' +
    '    max-width: 400px;      ' +
    ' } '
);

document.body.appendChild( box );

box.innerHTML = '';



var searchButton = document.createElement( 'div' );
searchButton.className = 'mySearchButton';
searchButton.textContent = 'Open';



GM_addStyle( 
    ' .mySearchButton {           ' +
    '    background: #aaa;       ' +
    '    border: 1px solid #777; ' +
    '    padding: 1px;           ' +
    '    margin-left: 8px;       ' +
    '    float: right;           ' +
    '    cursor: pointer;        ' +
    ' } '
);
box.insertBefore( searchButton, box.nextSibling );


searchButton.addEventListener ('click', countit);



localStorage.setItem('test', '5');


alert(localStorage.getItem('test'));



function countit () {

    localStorage.clear();
    alert(localStorage.getItem('test'))

}
```

Why doesn't it work on the second site?  Could the site have made it impossible to create your own buttons or something?

Update: OK, I discovered the problem but no clue how to fix it...  If you go to the second link and scroll down the page you'll notice my button disappears under the login sidebar... the button will only work at the very bottom of the page under the copyright notice.

NEW Question: How do I find and bypass whatever is overlaying my button?

Comment: Works fine in mine. Are your greasemonkey include and excludes set up correctly?

Comment: @Chris I kinda figured it out!  Edited question!

Comment: You could just change the zindex to some massively high number so it sits on top of everything else

Comment: What is 'zindex'?  Actually though, now I'm trying to remember how to put it in the footer.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/